# What is the difference between EJS and underscore.js' .template()

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, underscore.js-templating

Both seem to be doing very similar things, in a similar way.

- Both let you embed javascript into the templates, and have the same 3
  types of tags -unescaped replace, escaped replace, embed js-.
- Both have the ability to 'precomile' the template by creating the
  generator function.
- Also, both can be used as the template engine
  for express/node.js. (and in the browser, and everywhere else that supports js).

So when having to choose beween EJS and underscore.js templates: what things should be taken into account? Are they the same thing with just different name? If this is the case, why is it that there are 2 template engines so similar?

Comment: the `<%..%>` tags are the only similarity the tools share, underscores template its not a full functional template tool its not meant to be used in websites to write entire templates to produce html but for smaller things, `EJS` on the other side its just that its meant to be used as template language, with includes,escape and much more..underscores template became popular because backbone uses them , for small templates its great but nothing more than that.